# In Jmeter, Unable to extract only the first key from a JSON response

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to extract the first key from the json response, which should be passed as an input for next HTTP request in `Jmeter`.

This is my input (javascript object):

```
Object({"details": { "key1": {"s_1": "s_v", "s_2": "s_v" }, "key2": {"s_1": "s_v", "s_2": "s_v" } }})
```

I need to get `"key1"` in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try "JSON Path PostProcessor" in Post Processors and the expression may be "$..key1".

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the request which returns the above response.
2. Configure the Regular Expression Extractor as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `key_1`
   - Regular Expression: `"key1": {(.+?)}`
   - Template: `$1$`
3. Refer the extracted value as `${key_1}` where required

You can test your Regular Expressions using "RegeExp Tester" mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

Demo:

[image: Regexp Tester]

References:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl5 Regex Cheat Sheet](http://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)